# Using jq with bash to run command for each object in array

Tags: bash, jq

How can I run a Bash command for every JSON object in a JSON array using `jq`? So far I have this:

```
cat credentials.json | jq -r '.[] | .user, .date, .email' | mycommand -u {user} -d {date} -e {email}
```

This doesn't seem to work. How can I take the parameters out of the JSON array into my command?

My JSON file looks something like this:

```
[
   "user": "danielrvt",
   "date": "11/10/1988",
   "email": "myemail@domain.com",
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to output each record in something like TSV format, then read that from a shell loop.

```
jq -r '.[]|[.user, .date, .email] | @tsv' |
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r user date email; do
    mycommand -u "$user" -d "$date" -e "$email"
  done
```

`jq` itself doesn't have anything like a `system` call to run an external command from within a filter, although it seems that [they are working on it](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/147).

Comment: `IFS=$'\t'` is not working when I use this in Makefile. Can you suggest any other way?

Comment: `make` is probably using `/bin/sh`, not `bash`, and it doesn't support `$'...'`-style quoting.

Answer (score 49):

With xargs:

```
curl localhost:8082/connectors | jq .[] | xargs -L1 -I'{}' curl -XDELETE 'localhost:8082/connectors/{}'
```

Or equivalently, to show the output of that first curl:

```
echo '["quickstart-file-sink4","quickstart-file-source","quickstart-file-sink","quickstart-file-sink2","quickstart-file-sink3","quickstart-file-source2"]' | jq .[] | xargs -L1 -I'{}' curl -XDELETE 'localhost:8082/connectors/{}'
```

`jq .[]` strips off one level of containment, so that a list becomes output as one line per item.

`xargs -L1` processes one line at a time

`xargs -I'{}'` specifies that the string `{}` be replaced with the input line when invoking the following command.

`xargs` is essentially a map operator for the shell.

Comment: This is an excellent option for iterating over an array of values and executing a command for each value. It does not require a multi-line script nor does it require a step to generate commands and a step to execute them. `xargs` is a great command.

Comment: I copied it letter for letter and it does not work: curl: (3) empty string within braces in URL position 28:
localhost:8082/connectors/{}

When doing a simple 'xargs echo' output of jq will print, but never with replacement token :(

Comment: I had issues using the piped `xargs` command as shown in the answer, but this answer definitely got me headed down the right path!

For those interested, I ended up replacing the arguments with the more verbose config flag versions, with the equivalent for this question being `curl localhost:8082/connectors | jq .[] | xargs --max-lines=1 --replace={} curl -XDELETE 'localhost:8082/connectors/{}'` (I also used jq's `-r` flag before chaining).

Comment: only part that needed a change here is the `jq .[]` should actually be `jq '.[]'`

Answer (score 33):

You could have `jq` output the commands to execute, something like

```
.[] | "mycommand \(.user|@sh) \(.date|@sh) \(.email|@sh)"
```

Then execute it. Something like

```
bash <(jq -r '.[] | "mycommand \(.user|@sh) \(.date|@sh) \(.email|@sh)"' foo)
```

Comment: \(.propname) was all I needed. Is the |@sh piping each individual property? How is that different from \(.user)

Comment: The @sh guarantees each parameter is properly quoted so the shell doesn't wordsplit or expand globs if that's what gets output. Suppose someone manages to drop a file like `{"email": "daniel;rm -rf *", ...}`

Answer (score 22):

Here is another variation which I based on the answer from @chepner.

```
echo "$config" | jq -c '.[]' |
while IFS=$"\n" read -r c; do
    echo "start"
    host=$(echo "$c" | jq -r '.host')
    echo $host
    echo "end"
done
```

I used jq's -c option to output "compact" jsons, so they are all on one line.

In combination with `IFS=$"\n"`, I was able to loop over each item in the input json's array and do what I wanted to do.

So, with an input of

```
[
 {
  "host": "host1",
  "settings": {}
 },
 {
  "host": "host2",
  "settings": {}
 }
]
```

the output is

```
start
host1
end
start
host2
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same problem recently where xargs doesn't help that much due to the relatively complicated set of arguments I wanted to pass around. Thus I implemented an `sh` filter (and its friends) to jq. I haven't yet had enough time to write documentation and tests for it so not creating a PR for it to become a part of the official codebase yet. So now it's only for the ones who are willing to compile this version themselves:

https://github.com/haochenx/jq/tree/sh-support

Comment: I looked at your code.  I like the idea.  Some of the code you added to `src/builtin.c` is repetitive and needs to be simplified, but I think you should open a pull request against stedolan/jq.

Comment: nice solution - did you opened a PR?